# Why data is not passing from parent to its child2 component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Problem is: -React=>there is one parent component and it has 2 child components, data is available in child1 , I am taking  data from child 1  passing it to its parent by child to parent  method and that data is getting in parent component in console panel,now that data I am sending it from parent to its child2 component as props but data is not fetching. It is coming as empty array. Please help me for this. Note : data is in array format.

```
const parent=()=>{
const [item,setitem]=useState([])

const getData=(value)=>{
setitem(value)
}

<child1 getData={getData} item={item} setitem={setitem}/>
<child2 item={item} setitem={setitem}/>


}
export default parent

-------------------------------------

const child1=()=>{
const selectedItem=(props)=>{
props.getData(selectFood)==============>Note:  already selectFood has data.
props.setitem(selectFood)
}
return(
<div>
<button onClick={selectedItem}>Done</button>
</div>
)

}
# export default child1

-------------------------------------------- 

const child2=(props)=>{
console.log(props. item) ---------------->`but here data is not fetching from its parent`
}
export default child2
```

Comment: Initially the item in child2 is going to be empty array. Once the button onclick runs, the setitem callback runs and then you'll get the updated array in child2 component. You dont have to getData callback from parent if you're only calling the setitem which you have already passed to child1.

Comment: As you said , I removed getData from passing parent to child1 and only passing setitem but also data is not getting in child2

Comment: Your child1 doesn't even have props defined, you probably get error in the console

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just pass your `item` and `setItem` into your children like so:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <Child1 setItem={setItem} />
      <Child2 item={item} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Then use `setItem` in `Child1` to update the state:

```
const Child1 = (props) => {
  let selectFood = ["1", "2"];
  const { setItem } = props;
  const selectedItem = () => {
    setItem(selectFood);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={selectedItem}>Done</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And access the state in `Child2`:

```
const Child2 = (props) => {
  const { item } = props;

  console.log(item);
};
```

[image: Edit goofy-gagarin-z83rnl]

---

Or you can create a context in the parent using `createContext`:

```js
export const ItemContext = createContext();

const Parent = () => {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you can use the `ItemContext.Provider` to pass your state into child components:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

return (
  <>
    <ItemContext.Provider value={{ item, setItem }}>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
    </ItemContext.Provider>
  </>
);
```

Now you can access the objects passed into the child components by importing the context and extract them using `useContext`:

```js
import { ItemContext } from "./Parent";

const Child1 = () => {
    const { setItem } = useContext(ItemContext);
    /* ... */
}
```

[image: Edit modest-andras-uc15r5]